# How can I get list of artists from spotify API without using any ID'S

Tags: spotify

I am creating a music app using Spotify APIS. I want to list artists from Spotify without using any IDs.
    if we have any id then we can fetch artist details.
    link:GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/{id}
    If there are multiple artists IDS.
    link: GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists 
    Are there any options to get Spotify artist details without using any IDS?

Answer (score -1):

You can **Search** for Artists on Spotify using [Search for an Item](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/search) and select the **artist** type then you just need the name of the artist, you'll then get the basic artist information, along with their Id which you could use in other calls to get information about that Artist from Spotify

```
https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=ArtistName%type=artist
```